# Questions regarding Revival badge

Tags: support, badges

One day I got 2 Upvotes for [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17912/how-many-mutts-did-adi-shankaracharya-establish-in-his-lifetime/21207#21207) answer which was answered by me more than 60 days later. Then I received revival badge. But when I edited the answer, somebody removed their Upvote, now I am having 1 Upvote in that answer. But still the revival badge awarded to me is not get back.

- Why it is so?
- If any other upvoted the answer I got 2 upvotes again, then can I receive the badge revival for second time for the same question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, regular badges are not revoked when they are not applicable. This [only happens on tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work/63836#63836). They are revoked immediately if the criteria is no longer applicable.

---

> If any other upvoted the answer I got 2 upvotes again, then can I receive the badge revival for second time for the same question?

No, you will not be awarded the same badge again for the same answer. But there's a possibility to @KeshavSrinivasan to get a badge because he posted the answer earlier than you.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)